# How can I restrict a user to entering only numeric values in a specific cell in a DataGridView column?

Tags: datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` control in which I want to restrict the user to entering only numeric values for a cell under a particular column. How can I accomplish this type of validation in `DataGridView` cells?

It is possible when I create a simple text box, but how can I validate a `DataGridView` Cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the type of data the column will hold as the following code snippet illustrates:

```
var columnSpec = new DataColumn();
columnSpec.DataType = <your type>
// Other initialisation
dataTable.Columns.Add(columnSpec);

dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

If you are working directly on the `DataGridView` then the `DataGridViewColumn` class has the following property:

> ValueType - Gets or sets the data type of the values in the column's cells.

If you create your columns using this class rather than the more specialised classes `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` etc. this might do want you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't find DatType property in DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column in DataGridView control

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to define your DataGridView? My answer assumed that the data was in a DataTable and the DataGridView is just for display

Comment: There wont be a DataType property in DataGridViewTextBoxColumn as it already has type - Text.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cellValidating` event:

```
Grid.CellValidating += new DataGridViewCellValidatingEventHandler(Grid_CellValidating);

Grid_CellValidating(object sender, args)
{
XXXX
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add an event of EditingControlShowing
- In EditingControlShowing, check that if the current cell lies in the desired column.
- Register a new event of KeyPress in EditingControlShowing(if above condition is true).
- Remove any KeyPress event added previously in EditingControlShowing.
- In KeyPress event, check that if key is not digit then cancel the input.

Example:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Desired Column
            {
                TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (tb != null)
                {
                    tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
                }
            }
        }

private void Column1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```